# Azure Billing API returning 403

Tags: java, azure

I have spent several days trying to figure this out, looking at all the info I could find on the Azure website, the Azure git hubs, and all the relevant stack overflow posts.  I hope I am missing something simple.

I am using the example java code being posted around the web to obtain a token:

```
try {
        exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/8e4f0713-5eea-4da0-99c0-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        true, exec);
        ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(webClientID, clientSecret);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", cred, null);
        result = future.get();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Exception " + e);
    } finally {
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    if (result == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return result.getAccessToken();
```

This generates a token which I place into the request header:

```
Authorization: Bearer -token-

The GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/758ad253-cbf5-4b18-8863-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview%26%24filter%3DOfferDurableId+eq+%27MS-AZR-0003p%27+and+Currency+eq+%27USD%27+and+Locale+eq+%27en-US%27+and+RegionInfo+eq+%27US%27
```

Returns 403 code:

```
Exception: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/758ad253-cbf5-4b18-8863-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview%26%24filter%3DOfferDurableId+eq+%27MS-AZR-0003p%27+and+Currency+eq+%27USD%27+and+Locale+eq+%27en-US%27+and+RegionInfo+eq+%27US%27
```

Headers:
[0] null: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

[1] Cache-Control: no-cache

[2] Pragma: no-cache

[3] Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

[4] Expires: -1

[5] x-ms-failure-cause: gateway

[6] x-ms-request-id: e4ad9253-e034-481d-aba0-f46902b7057f

[7] x-ms-correlation-request-id: e4ad9253-e034-481d-aba0-f46902b7057f

[8] x-ms-routing-request-id: EASTUS:20151103T205103Z:e4ad9253-e034-481d-aba0-f46902b7057f

[9] Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

[10] Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 20:51:02 GMT

[11] Connection: close

[12] Content-Length: 303

I did all the setup on the Azure mgmt console, to create the App in Azure AD, get the clientID & client secret, etc.  The SSL/HTTPS code is:

```
           azureURL = new java.net.URL(url);

        con = (HttpsURLConnection)azureURL.openConnection();
        con.disconnect();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setSSLSocketFactory(MyUtils.getSSLSocketFactory());
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2015-06-01-preview");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String token = getAccessTokenFromServicePrincipalCredentials();
        if (token != null) {
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            con.connect();
            in = (InputStream)con.getContent();
            InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        } else {
            logger.warn("unable to obtain prices");
        }
```

Any suggestions on how to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're getting an access token for the `Service Principal` (i.e. the application itself). Please make sure that you grant this Service Principal user at least `Reader` role on your Azure Subscription. I believe you're getting this error because this user doesn't have any access to your Azure Subscription.

Please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/ (`Manage access using the Azure Management Portal` section) on how you can assign role.

Comment: Thanks, I added the application itself as a contributor and the 403 went away. Now I am getting a 404 file not found.

Comment: You should get more details in the error itself. Would you mind sharing those details please?

Comment: This is the exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/758ad253-cbf5-4b18-8863-3eed0825bf07/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview%26%24filter%3DOfferDurableId+eq+%27MS-AZR-0003p%27+and+Currency+eq+%27USD%27+and+Locale+eq+%27en-US%27+and+RegionInfo+eq+%27US%27

Comment: Can you do one thing please? Take the URL and the bearer token and run that in Google Postman or Fiddler. You should see more details there.

Comment: yeah, yeah...just a sec

Comment: I just started to get something back from postman, looks ok....perhaps some backend delay or something happened. Programmatically, I still get the 404 file not found so there must be something wrong with the java connection or URL.

Comment: Please see if this thread helps you with the error you're getting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255823/httpurlconnection-java-io-filenotfoundexception.

Answer (score 0):

As we can’t call Usage & Rate Card APIs via certificate with HTTPS requests. As it is mentioned:

> All of the tasks that you do on resources using the Azure Resource Manager must be authenticated with Azure Active Directory

on [Authenticating Azure Resource Manager requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx).

So you got a 403 issue.

Please try to build common HTTP request for the REST APIs with the request header Content-Type and Authorization which is mentioned on [Resource Usage (Preview)](http://Resource%20Usage%20(Preview)).

Also you can test to get the info you want in HTTP request build tool, like:

[image]

And here is a similar thread [How to use Management certificate based authentication for making REST API calls to Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946287/how-to-use-management-certificate-based-authentication-for-making-rest-api-calls) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

For the file not found the reply is:

java.io.FileNotFoundException:

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/758ad253-cbf5-4b18-8863-3eed082xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview%26%24filter%3DOfferDurableId+eq+%27MS-AZR-0003p%27+and+Currency+eq+%27USD%27+and+Locale+eq+%27en-US%27+and+RegionInfo+eq+%27US%27

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

[1] Cache-Control: no-cache

[2] Pragma: no-cache

[3] Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

[4] Expires: -1

[5] x-ms-failure-cause: gateway

[6] x-ms-request-id: 8bd5ea3a-5a5f-4eb5-86b5-bd6581f94e00

[7] x-ms-correlation-request-id: 8bd5ea3a-5a5f-4eb5-86b5-bd6581f94e00

[8] x-ms-routing-request-id: EASTUS:20151119T181954Z:8bd5ea3a-5a5f-4eb5-86b5-bd6581f94e00

[9] Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

[10] Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 18:19:53 GMT

[11] Content-Length: 348

Let me see what else I can get...